# FluentNHibernate Mixing Fluent and Auto Mappings

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Is there a clean way to mix fluent mappings with automappings? Ideally, I'd like to say "if I don't have a ClassMap for a domain object, then automap it".  Is there a recommended approach? I'd rather not use attributes on my business objects that are data access related (ex: [UseAutoMapping]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - check out [IAutoMappingOverride](http://jagregory.com/writings/fluent-nhibernate-auto-mapping-overrides-and-alterations/)

Basically, any mappings which override the Automapping behaviour need to implement this interface.

e.g.

```
public class MyClassMap : IAutoMappingOverride<MyClass>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<MyClass> mapping)
    {
        mapping.IgnoreProperty(host => host.HostName);
        mapping.Table("BobsHardware");
    }
}
```